# How to upgrade JavaHL on Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu, subclipse, javahl

### Environment

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Eclipse Java EE Indigo Service Release 1
- Subclipse 1.8.x
- libsvn1 1.6.12
- svn 1.7.x

### Problem

Subclipse 1.8.x [requires JavaHL version 1.7.x](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL). I need Subclipse 1.8.x in order to use svn 1.7.x.

Ubuntu 10.10 does not have subversion 1.7 packages or libsvn1 1.7 packages.

### Question

Is there any way to upgrade the libsvn1 package on Ubuntu, possibly by configuring another package repository or installing the package directly? If the latter is possible, where can I find the libsvn1/JavaHL packages? Surely someone else must be trying to use svn 1.7 on this Ubuntu version right?

Comment: Why is there a close vote? From the FAQ questions can cover, "software tools commonly used by programmers", or "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to mess around with your Ubuntu packages while you wait for them to update to SVN 1.7.x, one thing you can do is install the CollabNet client RPM.  This installs into a private namespace (/opt/CollabNet_Subversion) so it does not alter any of your Ubuntu packages.  You can install the RPM by using the "alien" package.  We have had Subclipse users confirm that this client works for them.

http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/linux.html

Answer (score 53):

(Copied from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032252/getting-subclipse-to-work-on-ubuntu-64-and-indigo-incompatible-javahl-library/9503592#9503592))

Remove your existing libsvn-java:

```
sudo apt-get purge libsvn-java
```

Then, add the following software source and re-install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

(found [here](http://www.sidewaysforward.com/2012/02/upgrading-to-svnjavahl-1-7-x-in-ubuntu/))

**Update**: for Ubuntu 14 use the subversion 1.8 repo instead

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.8
```

(Thanks to @YetAnotherMatt's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25294304/222438))

Comment: This worked. I could not find any other practical solution under Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: But its not working for Trusty Tahr (Ubuntu 14.04)? Do you have any other solution which will help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem is that the jni location changed in 14.04 from /usr/lib/jni to something like /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni

I recommend editing your eclipse ini's vmargs java.library.path setting thus

- ORIGINAL: -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
- NEW:  -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni

This setting determination from where eclipse expects to locate the library files

Answer (score 2):

@VishalKale, and anyone else trying to follow @jlb's instructions  on more recent versions of Ubuntu, use the Subversion-1.8 repository instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.8
```

For more details: [Getting subclipse to work on Ubuntu 64 and Indigo - Incompatible JavaHL library loaded. 1.7.x or later required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032252/getting-subclipse-to-work-on-ubuntu-64-and-indigo-incompatible-javahl-library/25294245#25294245)