# Getting subclipse to work on Ubuntu 64 and Indigo - Incompatible JavaHL library loaded. 1.7.x or later required

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, javahl

How do I fix this?

I am on ubuntu 64 using Eclipse indigo.  I installed http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x.

At first I got this error:

> Failed to load JavaHL Library.
>   These are the errors that were encountered:
>   no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>   no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>   no svnjavahl in java.library.path
>   java.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

Then after some googling I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

Then in the eclipse.ini I added this line:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

I then created this directory and contents:

```
~/.eclipse/eclipserc
VMARGS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni"
```

I am still getting this error:

```
Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required.
```

What more can I do?

Comment: I hope this helps someone.  I just used http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x and it worked.  

I did add the first before I installed so I dont know if that had any effect.

    sudo apt-get install libsvn-java

Answer (score 25):

Remove your existing libsvn-java:

```
sudo apt-get purge libsvn-java
```

Then, add the following software source and re-install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

(found [here](http://www.sidewaysforward.com/2012/02/upgrading-to-svnjavahl-1-7-x-in-ubuntu/))

thanks to @codemonkeybr: also update your eclipse.ini with `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni`

(or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni` or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni` depending on your system ...)

**Update** for Ubuntu 14 use Subversion 1.8 instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.8
```

Comment: works great!! just dont forget to set the -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni pointing to the right place

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 64 (12.04 or 12.10), try `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni`

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

And on Ubuntu 32 (12.04), modify the eclipse.ini:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are reluctant to install any software from third party repositories I would just recommend to install version 1.6.x of Subclipse instead of the latest 1.8.x one.
Details can be found [here](http://arobenko-tech.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/getting-subclipse-to-work-with-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

For those following @jlb's instructions above but getting the following (or similar) error:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dominik-stadler/subversion-1.7/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

That repository hasn't been updated for later versions of Ubuntu, but the equivalent subversion-1.8 repository has.

First, remove the 1.7 repository in Synaptic Package Manager (instructions here: http://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-repositories-in-ubuntu/ ), then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

And follow the rest of the instructions on editing eclipse.ini as above.

Answer (score 0):

check out this topic:
[Installing Subversion JavaHL library in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313164/installing-subversion-javahl-library-in-mac-os-x)

u may change the SVN interface of Eclipse to SVNKit(pure java)