# Installing Subversion JavaHL library in Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I installed Subclipse in Eclipse using Eclipse Marketplace. I keep on getting a pop window with the message

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

This is the link that is suggested to be visited.
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

Under Mac OS X I find a link to OpenCollabNet but I can't find binaries on that link, would much appreciate if someone could help me locate the link to binaries.
And also is there a way to install Subversion JavaHL library via macports, if yes what is the command to do so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using SVNKit is a valid option, but I still prefer JavaHL.  The volunteer that was providing OSX binaries hosted by CollabNet stopped making them, so they do not have a Subversion 1.7 version available, only 1.6.

I updated the Subclipse JavaHL wiki page. The page directs people to use MacPorts or HomeBrew.  Those are the best options for getting JavaHL.  I use MacPorts.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

Answer (score 21):

You can also switch to the pure-Java implementation via "Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN inteface" and choose the entry with "SVNKit". This way you remove any dependency on native code and get rid of these errors. [Eclipse Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqMBZ.png)

If you are missing the SVNKit-choice, verify if you have installed the plugin "SVNKit Client Adapter" from CollabNet! [image: Install SVNKit Adapter]