# What SVN connector do I need to use for Eclipse Juno Subversive on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, connector

I'm using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.7.5.  I installed Subversive and also have this version of svn installed on my Mac:

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:clever davea$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Apr  3 2013, 12:31:42
```

I'm having problems getting SVN to work with Eclipse, in particular, when trying to select the appropriate SVN Connector.  I'd like to use "Native JavaHL" but when going Eclipse -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN and clicking the "SVN Connector" tab, there appears to be an error when trying to select JavaHL.  The menu option next to "SVN Connector" states:

```
Native JavaHL 0x00100000: Cannot load libraries: Could not initialize class org.tigris.subversion.javahl…
```

Unfortunately the message cuts off, so my question is, what is the proper way to install this connector (or should I be using a different one) so that Eclipse/SVN/Subversive can work in peace and harmony together?

Comment: Why don"t you use Subversive's own connector?

Comment: Looking around, I found this svn connector for eclipse that looks promising: http://subclipse.tigris.org/ I don't know if its any good but maybe it will work around your issue.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working for Eclipse Juno 3.8.2 on my Mac (Mountain Lion):

- I added the Subversive plugin to Eclipse using Help->Install New Software and select Collaboration->Subversive SVN Team Provider
- I installed the JavaHL library using MacPorts: `sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal`, as described [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b). (The link also includes a Homebrew command: `brew install --universal --java subversion`)
- I downloaded the "allplatforms" 3.0.4 connectors archive from [Subversive Connector Archives for Subversive 1.0/1.1](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/builds/) and extracted this to a local directory
- Added this directory as a local repository in Eclipse Install New Software->Add.. which then gives you the ability to add the bundled SVN connectors, JavaHL or SVNKit. I used Native JavaHL 1.8 implementation for my SVN 1.8 install.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [installation instructions](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php) for Subversive, you find there the following remark:

> For all other platforms (MacOS, Linux, etc.), you should install a platform-independent pure-Java SVNKit connector, or additionally install a package that contains JavaHL binaries for the target platform.

And later, it is stated:

> If you've installed JavaHL connector on a non-Win32 platform or if you want to use a different set of JavaHL binaries, you should do the following ...

with a recipe to make it known to Eclipse.

On an [older blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225132803/http://matthew.mceachen.us:80/blog/how-to-set-up-native-subversion-javahl-with-subclipse-on-mac-os-x-332.html), I found the following:

> `sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings`

I do not know if that is true any more, the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313164/installing-subversion-javahl-library-in-mac-os-x) references the [explanation at tigris](https://web.archive.org/web/20200701141815/http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b), so the command from above is true if you use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), for [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh), the command is

> `brew install --universal --java subversion`

Comment: Hi, I was able to run the "sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings" command successfully, but after restarting my system and firing up Eclipse, the error I mentioned above remains.

Comment: Have you updated your PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so that the installed libraries (`/opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib`) are included?

Comment: Tried that too, but sadly, the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the JAVAHL folder to eclipse.ini and restarting it?
For example, for running Subclipse in my linux distro, I added this line to eclipse.ini (in eclipse root folder)

Below -vmargs

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
```

Comment: Hi, I added "-Djava.library.path=/opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib" to the end of my "/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini" file, but alas, no dice.