# JavaHL in Eclipse cannot be loaded while LibraryPath is overwritten

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, javahl, library-path

I use Subclipse with JavaHL in Eclipse Luna. Therefore I adapted my `java.library.path` property to load the libs as described [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe).

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms400m
-Xmx8192m
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
```

The libs are in the correct directory:

```
user@dev:~$ locate libsvnjavahl-1.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
```

But when I start eclipse I see an error message with a different `java.library.path`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to the pure-Java implementation via "Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN inteface" and choose the entry with "SVNKit". This way you remove any dependency on native code and get rid of these errors. Eclipse Preferences

If you are missing the SVNKit-choice, verify if you have installed the plugin "SVNKit Client Adapter" from CollabNet in Eclipse.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313934/411846) for more details.