# My SVN Connector in Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0) doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

My SVN Connector in Eclipse shows the following message:
[Picture of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHCo8.png)

Can someone help me solve this error? I have Subclipse and Subversive installed.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install only 1 I think. Not sure if installing both causes new problems.

There are several issues with both subclipse and subsersive.

Both I think can use a java library called " SVNKit" or use a native library "JavaHL" to access SVN.

The error complains about javahl missing. You manually hjave to install javahl in your system, eg [How to upgrade JavaHL on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434449/how-to-upgrade-javahl-on-ubuntu). But even then it often does not work. I think this is due to version conflicts or so...

The alternative, svnkit, is less prone to such version conflicts. Adapters are not used by default however, apparently nobody has time to fix the libraries to use them properly. So they sometimes work, sometimes not. There also is a problem with java >9 because the svnkit library (at least the usual version) uses some java calls that have been restricted/security-walled in newer java. Not sure how/why/which versions, it also depends on the OS. You need to dig down in the preferences/settings to disable the JavaHL and turn on the SVNKit.

Overall both adapters need a lot of massaging and it's totally unclear to me which adapter works on which system and eclipse version.